# Google Storage filename pattern

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am writing API to push files to Google Storage using signed string. I wonder is there any Google Cloud API for Java to check if filename is correct due to Google Storage object naming requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any API to do this but the [requirements of bucket names and object names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming) are documented and should be fairly straightforward to implement.